# Remove device from iCloud

Tags: icloud, find-my-iphone

I sold my iPad (after restoring it and deleting all accounts/data), but it still shows up in iCloud settings under "Devices". Since I don't have access to the iPad anymore, how can I delete it from iCloud.com?

Answer (score 1):

First, contact the new owner, and ask him/her to enable Airplane mode. Once that's done, visit https://www.icloud.com/#find, and select the device. You should now have the ability to click "Remove from Account".

[image]